# Make 1 jpeg file with separately named plot for each original csv file in R, jpeg function?

Tags: r, function, csv, plot, jpeg

I am trying to create a loop in R that does the following. I have a map with for example 10 datasets: file1.txt.csv, file2.txt.csv, etc. Now I simply want to create one graph per data set and output that, so that I get file1.jpeg, file2.jpeg, etc.

This is what I got so far:

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.txt.csv")

for (fileName in fileNames) {

VolumeData <- read.delim(fileName, header = FALSE) 
# convert data frame to data table 
VolumeDatat <- VolumeData [, -(7:14)] 
# set column names
setnames(VolumeDatat, c("MCS", "cell_type", "cell_number", "total_volume"))

jpeg(sub(".txt.csv",".jpg"))
plot(VolumeDatat$total_volume~VolumeDatat$MCS,type="l")
dev.off()
}
```

And I guess that

```
jpeg (sub(".txt.csv",".jpg"))
```

is the essential part for this, but I can't figure this out, also the arguments for jpeg in the library didn't help me much further.
First, I tried with jpeg (fileName.jpeg), which works, but only for the last file in the loop as the file gets overwritten for each time you run the script, e.g. each file.
So now I tried it with some sub-function, cause I thought that might work, but by doing so, I got:

```
Error in sub(".txt.csv", ".jpg") : 
argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Could anyone help me with this? I'd be very grateful!

Comment: You probably want `sub(".txt.csv",".jpg",fileName)`.

Comment: from `sub` help : `sub(pattern, replacement, x, ...)`, you're not providing x (ie, you're saying what to replace and by what but not where...). Message is pretty clear to me.

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks to you both!